# Unity WaitForSecondsRealtime doesn't working when time.timescale = 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animation that I want to play after my character dies. I'm trying to activate the Game Over screen after this animation is complete, but it doesn't work after `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3f);`

Here is my code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "DeathArea")
        {
           StartCoroutine(Dead());
        }
    }


IEnumerator Dead() 
    {   
        animDie.SetActive(true);
        animDeath.SetTrigger("Die");
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3f);
        animDie.SetActive(false);
        isDead = true;
        deathScreen.SetActive(true);
        managerGame.Medal();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The most likely reason for coroutines to stop working is that object from they were called were deactivated. Can't see that happening here though. Try logging something after each instruction or use a debugger, so we can see how far it reaches.

Comment: I get a response from the debug before yield return, but none of the commands work for the second part.

Comment: Consider this piece of code, I hope it will be readable in the comments: IEnumerator Dead()
    {
        print("Before scale");
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        print("After scale");
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3f);
        print("After 3 sec");
    }
If I remove the setActive(false) I will reach the last print, otherwise not. Is there a chance, that any other thing deactivates an object that this script is attached to?

Comment: Before Scale and After Scale respond but no response from After 3 Sec.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to present you what I tried, and to indicate, that it may not work if you deactivate an object. I'll ask again, Is there a chance, that any other thing deactivates an object that this script is attached to?

Comment: No, the code is normally OK. However, I had to add a waiting time for the animation, I couldn't get over it.

Comment: Animations triggered to play can be paused by Time.timeScale = 0 try making Time.timeScale = 1 again after your "yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3f);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an event/function to be called at the end of your animation.
Unity lets you do that through the Animation window really easily.

Add an event:

[image]

Choose your function from an attached script:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The coroutine is firing off, and Time.timescale is surely breaking things. I'd use it very sparingly if I were you, as this setting also persists between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

Using the `Time.timeScale = 0;` code is not a problem. The real problem is that I destroyed my character because it's a death animation. Since my character died, the rest of the code became inoperable.

So instead of killing it, I made it invisible using localScale.

But the solution above is much more useful. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -3):

Please change WaitForSecondsRealtime(3f) to WaitForSeconds(3f)

result
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

Comment: I tried but the result is still the same, thanks for the reply!

Comment: This doesn't help as with timeScale set to 0, you are going to wait forever. You have just written what you use, without knowing the difference between WaitForSeconds and WaitForSecondsRealtime.